# Preservation of arbitrary directory hierarchies in git repository

Tags: git

I'm trying to keep an ever growing/shrinking directory hierarchy modeled in a git repo with some `.gitkeep` files and I want to effectively have a `.gitignore` file that excludes all files under a given directory (where the `.gitignore` file resides) except for any `.gitkeep` file.

Currently I have (in `.gitignore` in the rpm directory):

```
/*
!.gitignore
!.gitkeep
```

This doesn't work because I think the 3rd line will not be effective if the directory that the `.gitkeep` file is in is ignored.

I've seen examples that do something like:

```
application/*
!application/language/

application/language/*
!application/language/gr/
```

But the directory hierarchy of what I hope to maintain isn't very static so maintaining this .gitignore file would be tedious.

I literally want as simple a `.gitignore` file as possible that ignores a whole directory (recursively) but allows a `.gitkeep` file to exist anywhere below said directory.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my example directory

```
.
├── app
│   ├── core
│   │   └── .gitkeep
│   ├── lang
│   │   ├── en
│   │   │   └── .gitkeep
│   │   ├── .gitkeep
│   │   ├── gr
│   │   │   ├── deep.txt
│   │   │   └── .gitkeep
│   │   └── more.txt
│   └── something.txt
├── .gitignore
└── .gitkeep
```

> I literally want as simple a `.gitignore` file as possible that ignores a whole directory (recursively)

Simply ignore everything in your `.gitignore`

```
*
```

> but allows a `.gitkeep` file to exist anywhere below said directory. Is this possible?

No problem, just force add it

```
git add -f app/lang/en/.gitkeep
```

Or add them all at once

```
find . | grep .gitkeep | xargs git add -f
```

Let's see

```
git status --ignored
```

> ```
> On branch master
>
> Initial commit
>
> Changes to be committed:
>   new file:   .gitkeep
>   new file:   app/core/.gitkeep
>   new file:   app/lang/.gitkeep
>   new file:   app/lang/en/.gitkeep
>   new file:   app/lang/gr/.gitkeep
>
> Ignored files:
>   .gitignore
>   app/lang/gr/deep.txt
>   app/lang/more.txt
>   app/something.txt
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Can I make a slight change:  I would prefer not to need to use the `-f` flag on `git add`.  If I do `touch dir/anotherdir/.gitkeep`, I'd like to see it as an untracked file, but if I do `touch dir/anotherdir/file`, I'd like to see no change in git status.